# How to resize an image dynamicly using android layouts

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I would like to put two images which are filled the row with equal widths. I have several rows like that. For wide screens such as tablets, the widths of images should be increased according to screen resolution.

What I want to do is exactly placing two images on a row in equal sizes, (%50 - %50 width like CSS) in all cases.

Is there any layout to perform this ? I've tried it with nested Linear and Relative layouts but cannot succeed.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: I have done many tries, so I dont have the exact code. I just tried to mimic "table" approach like html, <tr> <td> </td> </tr>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is just for 1 row. Both ImageViews will always occupy 50% of the row irrespective of device. Depending on how many rows you have, you may choose to use custom listview. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in my project, I don't really now what you need to achieve but in my project I just resize the image to respect a height equal to my width so the image will always be a perfect round picture...

Inside my activity I have this piece of code:

```
private RelativeLayout playerSpinner;

public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        int margin = (int)(45*getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(playerSpinner.getWidth() - margin,playerSpinner.getWidth() - margin);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        playerSpinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

Then I just added a ImageView inside my playerSpinner layout with MATC_PARENT or FILL_PARENT in the image properties.

Comment: how is its performance ? if I apply this to, for example, 10 playerSpinner object at one refresh, does it cause performance problems ?

Comment: Just remember to check if your row is already instantiate and don't do this again, just remember, you only instantiate the layout a few times when working with views, then you just alter the values for the same object...